# KeyListener Works at Random in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

Every time I run my app, it's a flip of the coin whether or not the **KeyListener** will function. If it works, it will not have any problems at any point afterwards, but if it's not functioning at the start of the app, it will never run until the program is closed out and started again.

```
public ThreeDimChessRunner() {
    record = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    winner = Player.NONE;
    game = new ThreeDimBoard(0);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);

    tm.start();
    screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    screenHeight = screenSize.height;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    ThreeDimChessRunner p = new ThreeDimChessRunner();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("3D Chess");  
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(p);
}
```

The class **ThreeDimChessRunner** extends `JPanel` and implements `KeyListener`, `ActionListener`, and `MouseInputListener`.

tm is a `Timer` object

screenSize is a `Dimension` object

Comment: is the JFrame non responsive ?  maybe it's too much work on the main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made viaible.

Focus can't be given to a component if the component hasn't been added to the frame and a KeyListener only works on components that have focus.

Random results generally occur because you are NOT creating the GUI on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. All Swing components and updates to Swing components should be done on the `EDT`. Read the section on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and example of the proper way to create your GUI.

Also, you should not be using a KeyListener to listen for events. As you have noticed they are unreliable since they depend on the component having focus. Instead you should be using [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). They can be configured to work even if the component doesn't have focus.

Comment: Ok, so adding the components before the frame is made viable fixed the problem. I'm very new to programming in general and sort of cobbled together my program with various tidbits of knowledge. I don't know... is the main method the same thing as the Event Dispatch Thread? Also, why do I need to use Key bindings? My program doesn't need to run when it doesn't have the focus, it only runs the single frame and nothing else outside the frame besides methods that alter the frame. So the Keylistener should be fine for that purpose, right?

Comment: `is the main method the same as the EDT? ` - no. Read the tutorial link I provide. It shows how to add your code to the EDT. `why do I need to use Key bindings?` - this is the newer and better approach. Again read the tutorial. Your simple example works now. But what about future applications when you have more than a single component on the frame. As soon as the panel loses focus the KeyListener will stop working. Learn the proper solution and it will work in all situations. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/).